# What did my friend mean? (Fukuoka Dialect)

Tags: phrases, colloquial-language, dialects, casual

I was talking to my friend at school today and I said her chicken she bought looked good. She replied with 「美味しいよとたい！」or 「美味しいよとだい！」possibly 「美味しいよ取ったい」or something along those lines. We live in Fukuoka and she uses 博多弁 quite often, very likely something only said here.
I understand the basic meaning but I've never heard it before, wondering if someone else has.
For context she bought this chicken and hadn't started eating it yet, but it's possible she had it in the past or has it often, in case that has something to do with the meaning.

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't sound like valid Hakata-ben. Maybe you should ask her?

Comment: It could have been V-しよっとたい for something along the lines of V-しているんだよ.